# get value from ram memory when ram address is stored as u32

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem getting the value from a ram address.

I have some limitations, i.e. it must be C code, and the adress of the stored information is given by a u32 value which is for example 0x001c0080.

The environment is for ARM and I use an eclipse sdk.
How can I get the data from this address?
I have a function, which can't be changed like:

```
u32 get_data(u32 address, u16 *status)
{
    ......
    u32 return_value ; 
    char cbuf[128];
    return_value= ?????   address ?????;
    sprintf(cbuf,"\tA:%x->%x",(int)address,(int)return_value);
    print (cbuf);
    return return_value; //here the u32 data stored in ram on address should be returned
}
```

Comment: You need to study embedded programming before programming ARM. This is very basic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the address into a pointer.

```
    return_value = *(u32 *) address;
```

Besides, it's recommended to use `<stdint.h>` instead of custom types. Your code could look like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t get_data(uint32_t address, uint16_t *status)
{
    // …
    uint32_t return_value;
    char cbuf[128];
    return_value = *(uint32_t *) address;
    sprintf(cbuf, "\tA:%x->%x", (int) address, (int) return_value);
    printf(cbuf);
    return return_value;
}
```

Be warned! Sooner or later, your project might migrate to a 64 Bit CPU. *Your code will not be portable.* Passing around addresses as integers instead of pointers is a bad idea, and even worse when assuming a pointer size. You should inspect the calling environment of your `get_data()` function to make sure that the address can be passed as pointer. If the address has to be passed as integer value, not as pointer, use `uintptr_t` instead, it will automatically be the correct size.

Besides, your format shouldn't require casts. You can use the formats from `<inttypes.h>` to avoid casts of format string arguments.

Say, your caller is `call_get_data` and the address `0x001c0080` is coming from a macro in a header file.

```
#include <foo.h> // Header which defines ADDRESS to be 0x001c0080 via #define ADDRESS 0x001c0080
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t get_data(uint32_t *address, uint16_t *status)
{
    // …
    uint32_t return_value;
    char cbuf[128];
    return_value = *address;
    sprintf(cbuf, "\tA:" PRIxPTR "->" PRIx32, address, return_value);
    printf(cbuf);
    return return_value;
}

void call_get_data(void)
{
    uint32_t addressValue = ADDRESS;
    uint32_t *address = (uint32_t *) addressValue;
    // …
    uint32_t returnValue = get_data(address, /* … */);
    // …
}
```

Note: That the environment is for ARM and you use Eclipse SDK does not matter.

Comment: "Your code will not be portable." So why not teach him to use `uintptr_t` instead of `uint32_t`.

Comment: @Lundin good point. I added that option to the corresponding paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can "typecast" the `u32 address` into a pointer of the desired type:

```
char *ptr = (char *)address;
sprint(cbuf, "\tC:%c", *ptr);
```

Or

```
u32 *ptr = (u32 *)address;
return_value = *ptr;
```

Comment: I get a constant value back on each ram address like:A:14fb10->34800000 A:14fb14->34800000 A:14fb18->34800000

Comment: @RicFutt Likely the bug is in the calling code then. Are you viewing the memory map in the debugger so you can verify the actual values?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, 
u32 *ptr = (u32 *)address;
return_value = *ptr;
workes fine.